# Snow blower : 0w30 or 5w30

Tags: maintenance, motor

My snow blower manual recommends 0w30 oil but every store recommends 5w30.

Which would be better for the longevity of my snow blower and why?

Comment: Oil debates are not really a matter of home improvement. That said, why would you not trust the engineers that built the machine? What resource at a store has as much credibility?

Comment: BTW, different oil weights tend to meet different specifications. They often contain different additive packages and have different base compounds. It's not _just_ a matter of viscosity. Be sure you match the spec codes required by the manufacturer.

Comment: This should be on the motor vehicle maintenance and repair SE, https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: If you have to ask if it's a scam, - whoops wrong speech but same idea.  Should you ignore manufacturer instructions for *your* unit and listen to random stockboys who aren't even authorized dealers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most engines have several weights of oil that are allowed, typically with one of them being the recommended weight. In addition, outside temperature affects which oil weights can be used. Most manuals will have a chart with temperature ranges for each oil weight.

My Toro snowblower lists 10W30 and 5W30 with the following temperature chart:
[image: Toro 721 snowblower oil weights]

I'm sure your snowblower's manual would list all oil weights that are allowed. I would suggest following the manual rather than some generic advice.

Comment: I generally agree, but it's worth mentioning that the "zero weights" often meet much stricter spec requirements. I wouldn't use a 5w oil in a machine that calls for a 0w oil. My BMW and my wife's Audi are good examples. Both call for zero-weights--one -20 and one -40. They're dramatically different than most 5w or 10w oils. YMMV.

Comment: @isherwood my car calls for 0W20 but allows for 5W30. I doubt a snowblower would require only 0W oil and forbid 5W, but unless OP will share the model we can't know for sure.

Comment: I'm sure there are exceptions, but you didn't mention any spec codes, which are the crux of my point. 5w oils may be allowed _if_ they meet the required specs.